# ubuntu 20.04 - reordering favorites?

Tags: favorites

default desktop, favorites bar at left, how do I move icons around?  Some of the more frequently used items are at the bottom, and Id like to move them to the top of the bar.

Installed dconf editor, but I cant seem to find obvious control of order in there....

Comment: Just drag them.

Comment: Im stupid, but not that stupid.  I have several 20.04 boxes, and on my latest install (Dell 5290), dragging the icons does not work.

Comment: Then you did something. It works fine on my 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04

Answer (score 0):

On 20.04, I can drag the icons with a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>Click</kbd>.